# Outlook can't show image into MimeMessage

Tags: java, image, email, outlook, html-email

I prepare my message as MimeMessage and try it open in different mail clients. In all client my message looks good but in Outlook and in another one, it looks wrong

```
...
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

// Text version
final MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setContent(email.getPlainMessage(), "text/plain");

// HTML version
final MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(email.getMessage(), "text/html");

//logo
PreencodedMimeBodyPart logo = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart(BASE_64_ENCODING);
logo.setHeader("Content-Type", IMAGE_PNG_CONTENT_TYPE + "; name=\"logo.png\"");
logo.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logo.png@01CFFF81.C72F8000>");
logo.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"logo.png\"");
logo.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", BASE_64_ENCODING);
logo.setContent(ENCODED_LOGO, IMAGE_PNG_CONTENT_TYPE);

// Create the Multipart. Add BodyParts to it.
final Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
mp.addBodyPart(logo);
mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

if (Objects.nonNull(email.getFilesToAttach())) {
    for (String filename : email.getFilesToAttach()) {
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1));
        mp.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
}

// Set Multipart as the message's content
mimeMessage.setContent(mp);

mimeMessage.setSubject(email.getSubject());
mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailConfig.getNoReplyEmailAddress()));

if (!emailConfig.getNoReplyEmailAddress().equals(email.getFromAddress())) {
    List<Address> replyTo = Arrays.asList(new InternetAddress(email.getFromAddress()));
    mimeMessage.setReplyTo(replyTo.toArray(new Address[replyTo.size()]));
}
mimeMessage.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email.getToAddress()));
mimeMessage.saveChanges();
...
```

And when I send it in outlook I see my logo as

[image: Broken logo]

but in another mail clients it looks good

Comment: Are you sure the `Content-Type` header should contain a comma, not a semicolon, before the `name=` part? That looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @haraldK You are right. I fixed it but it didn't help